# Prove that $\sum \tan \frac{n+1}{n^2}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that

$$\sum\tan \frac{n+1}{n^2}$$

diverges.

I know that the solution should be using the limit comparison test with $1/n$.

Therefore, I think that in the limit:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\tan \frac{n+1}{n^2}}{1/n}
$$

I should get a positive finite value... but, its not working, I don't know how to solve that limit...

I tried using L'Hospital, but its getting complicated: 
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2\frac{n+1}{n^2}}(\frac{n+1}{n^2})'}{-(1/n^2)}
$$

Help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|\tan \frac{n+1}{n^2}|}{\frac{1}{n}}$

Then we have

$L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{|\cos\frac{n+1}{n^2}|} \frac{|\sin\frac{n+1}{n^2}|}{\frac{1}{n}}$

$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{|\cos\frac{n+1}{n^2}|}\frac{n+1}{n} \frac{|\sin\frac{n+1}{n^2}|}{\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{1}{n}}$

$=\bigg(|\frac{1}{\cos\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n+1}{n^2}}|\bigg)\bigg(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n+1}{n}\bigg) \bigg(|\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin\frac{n+1}{n^2}}{\frac{n+1}{n^2}}| \bigg)$

$=(1)(1)\bigg(|\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin\frac{n+1}{n^2}}{\frac{n+1}{n^2}}| \bigg)$.

Let $x=\frac{n+1}{n^2}.$ Then $x \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. It follows that

$L=|\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}|=1.$

This proves that $\sum |\tan \frac{n+1}{n^2}|$ converges. It follows that $\sum \tan \frac{n+1}{n^2}$ converges.

Please let me know if there is any clarification necessary.

Comment: How did you think on that? thank you, understood.

Comment: The first thing I tried worked out. Sometimes you get lucky like that :)

Comment: @Jephph: I agree with the limit, but don't we need that $\tan \left(\frac{n+1}{n^2}\right) \geq 0$ to apply the comparison test?

Comment: I have made an edit. Does this clear things up?

Comment: @Jephph: sure, thanks! I have used the fact that $\frac{n+1}{n^2} \in (0,1)$ if $n \geq \left \lceil {\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}} \right \rceil =2$, so I have written $\sum_{n \geq 1} \tan \frac{n+1}{n^2}=\tan2+\sum_{n \geq 2} \tan \frac{n+1}{n^2}$ and now, since the tangent is positive in $(0,1)$, we have that the series from $n \geq 2$ converges by comparison test. Do you think this is correct? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes this works.

Answer (score 3):

That is very easy using *asymptotic analysis*, more precisely *equivalence* of functions:

We know that a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term, hence $$\frac{n+1}{n^2}\sim_\infty \frac n{n^2}=\frac 1n.$$
On the other hand, $\;\tan x\sim_0x$, hence, by substitution,
 $$\tan\frac{n+1}{n^2}\sim_\infty \frac{n+1}{n^2}\sim_\infty\frac 1n.$$

Comment: Thank you Bernard, but im not sure that i can use asymptotic analysis in my course, but dont delete the answer please, its still good and i learn from it, thanks.

Comment: It's only the notion of equivalent functions that I used. I learnt when I was a first year student.

Comment: I agree with the limit, but don't we need that $\tan \left(\frac{n+1}{n^2}\right) \geq 0$ to apply the comparison test?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do the comparison test, it suffices to let $1/n=x$ and argue that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\tan((n+1)/n^2)\over1/n}=\lim_{x\to0^+}{\tan(x+x^2)\over x}=\lim_{x\to0^+}{(1+2x)\sec^2(x+x^2)\over1}=1$$

using L'Hopital for the second equality.